# error_reporting not work correctly to show fatal errors

Tags: php

i have a page simply like this:

```
error_reporting(-1);
require('test.txt');
```

i know that test.txt not exists .i want to try **error_reporting()** function.
in this case that we pass number **-1** to function all error reported correctly like this:

```
Warning: require(test.txt) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\PHP_Class\session_5\errors.php on line 11
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'test.txt' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\PHP_Class\session_5\errors.php on line 11
```

and when we pass number **2** to function **like error_reporting(2)** only E_WARNING error reported and this is correct too:

```
Warning: require(test.txt) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\PHP_Class\session_5\errors.php on line 11
```

but when i pass number **1** to function like **error_reporting(1)** for report E_ERROR errors only , no error display. 
what is problem? please tell me

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on 5.3.10 too. Perhaps this is a bug that should be reported.

Comment: Looks like harry and Dan lee is correct. A compile_error is generated, instead of a run-time error :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think require doesn't throw an `E_ERROR` but an `E_COMPILE_ERROR`.
So please try it with `error_reporting(E_COMPILE_ERROR);`

Answer (score 3):

how about this

```
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) ;
```

this should give you all the errors you require

**UPDATE**

chk this url

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

it says

> include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR level error.

so this code will always give the compile error.... 
And the config above will be best suited for you production env..

Comment: Yes This Work fine. but why error_reporting(1) not work in this case. it is my Question????

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
error_reporting(64);
require('test.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper-way to do it if you want to suppress the error

```
error_reporting(E_COMPILE_ERROR );
require('test.txt');
```

It not `advice` such anyway  ..

Comment: thanks. but i want to report fatal error only. your suggest do not report any errors..